# pyntcloud to polyhedral from pointcloud with normals

Tags: python-3.x, point-clouds, polyhedra

I have a pointcloud which I imported to the pyntcloud libray as a series of points, it is a fully 3D pointcloud, as in it bounds forms a volume.

```
points = pd.DataFrame(points)   
points.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']
cloud = PyntCloud(points)
```

I calculate the normals

```
k_neighbors = cloud.get_neighbors(k=10)
cloud_norm=cloud
cloud_norm.add_scalar_field("normals", k_neighbors=k_neighbors)
```

I would like to generate a solid object, preferably a polyhedral, I've looked at the CGAL bindings and pymesh but I'm not finding a working solution. Any ideas?

The data is structured like this

```
cloud.points
                x           y           z    nx(11)    ny(11)    nz(11)
0      991.538025  267.574707  191.911194 -0.065332 -0.106776  0.992134
1      991.545227  267.598602  191.912704 -0.157886  0.069813  0.984986
2      991.546570  267.587189  191.913498 -0.124825 -0.085891  0.988454
3      991.548889  267.565887  191.910797 -0.082405 -0.210254  0.974168
4      991.549805  267.563507  191.911499 -0.094382 -0.256764  0.961855
5      991.552124  267.624298  191.910599 -0.192515  0.238861  0.951779
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudCompare has a plugin that can do this. It uses an open source plugin that does "Poisson reconstruction", see https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version12.00/
It Generates .ply files.